# How to use DOMSANITIZER(bypassSecurityTrustUrl) while calling the API

Tags: angular, angular-datatables, angular-dom-sanitizer

Getting XSS vulnerabilities while calling the API for fetching the data. So trying to add `DOMSANITIZER`, but its failing. Tried below code, please suggest me the solution.

```
 this.http.get(this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(dataUrl),{headers:headers}).subscribe(response => {
      this.persons = response.data.map(x=>({...x,check:false,test:x.firstName}));
      this.dtTrigger.next();
    });
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/column-names-as-tooltip-p65f2k)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DOMSANITIZER while using the API in following way.

1. **Import these:**

> ```
>     import {
>       Component,
>       OnInit,
>       ViewChild,
>       SecurityContext,
>     } from '@angular/core';
>     
>     import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
> ```

2. **Use this below code in your project where you are using this:**

> ```
> const dataUrl = this.domSanitizer.sanitize(
>       SecurityContext.RESOURCE_URL,
>       this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
>         'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/master/demo/src/data/data.json'
>       )
>     );
>
>     this.http.get(dataUrl).subscribe((response) => {
>       this.persons = response.data.map((x) => ({
>         ...x,
>         check: false,
>         test: x.firstName,
>       }));
>       this.dtTrigger.next();
>     });
> ```

**Important:**

This code is working on your stackblitz url.

[image]

I have also save it and you can go there to check it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/column-names-as-tooltip-wcw1f7?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts